# Spring Data JPA Questions

Tags: spring, jpa

I am new to Spring Data JPA. Previously I was using Hibernate, where I am persisting the entity with creating `SessionFactory` and `Session` and then call `save` or `persist` method to save the data.
Now here there are few questions for JPA.

1. JPA provided the JPA Repository where we have CRUD operation to persist data without writing the code to open `sessionFactory` and create the `session` as we do in hibernate. So it will use this internally. Means when we call Spring data JPA `save` method, is this call to Hibernate where it creates the `SessionFactory` and Create Session and then call this method.?
2. As in hibernate, the first-level cache is enabled by default. Is it the same here also, or in Spring data JPA we have to use some annotation for this.?
3. How can we enable second-level cache in Spring data JPA.?
4. Can we create our complete application with spring data JPA?
5. In Spring data JPA the save method is calling persist method internally. So if we need to call the `save` method of Hibernate, how can we do that?

There might be other questions, but it depends on the answer to the above items.

Thanks & Regards
Amitabh Pandey

Comment: 1. No you are using JPA which is using the `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager`. Not `SessionFactory` and `Session`. 2. Spring Data JPA is only a layer on top of JPA, everything else remains the same, 3. the same as you normally do in hibernate, 4. yes you can. 5. Don't just call save on the repository or use `Entitymanager.persist`.

Comment: For 3 ans .If i need to call evict method to remove the data from cache how i will do that as JpaRepository doesnot have evict method or remove method .

Comment: The fact that you are using Spring Data JPA doesn't mean you cannot use the EntityManager to call evict. As stated it is just a wrapper around JPA nothing more nothing less. It isn't a JPA implementation, it isn't a JPA extension it is a repository implementation around JPA.